# Launching an activity from inside a SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, surfaceview, android-context

I'm trying to start an Activity (StartGame) from inside of a SurfaceView once I touch in a certain spot. This code is inside the OnTouchEvent

It won't accept what I have below, of course, but I don't know what to put in the Context space.

I've tried my package (com.Juggle2.Menu), but that doesn't work, because it can't resolve it to a variable, and "this" doesn't work because it's a class. I don't know what else to try.

```
startActivity(new Intent(com.Juggle2.Menu, StartGame.class));
```

This does not work because "com.Juggle2.Menu cannot be resolved to a variable"

My Manifest is as follows

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Juggle2"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

  <activity android:name=".StartGame">
    </activity>
        <activity android:name = ".Help">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name = ".Options">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name = ".Credits">
        </activity>
</application>
```

And my project goes com.Juggle2>Menu.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try startActivity(new Intent(com.Juggle2.Menu.this, StartGame.class));

**Edit working:**

```
Context context = com.Juggle2.Menu.this.getContext();
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, StartGame.class));
```

Comment: That gives me a different error for the entire line:

The constructor Intent(Menu, Class<StartGame>) is undefined

Comment: Is the OnTouchEvent inside the class com.Juggle2.Menu?

Comment: Is com.Juggle2.Menu extending Activity?

Comment: No, it's extending SurfaceView. Is this a problem?

Comment: Try startActivity(new Intent(com.Juggle2.Menu.this.getContext(), StartGame.class));

Comment: Now I get a different error that says
_The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Menu_

Comment: Try:

    Activity act = (Activity) com.Juggle2.Menu.this.getContext();
    act.startActivity(new Intent(act, StartGame.class));

Comment: For the Activity act... statement I get _Type mismatch: cannot convert from Context to Activity_  But I cast it to an Activity and it compiles, but now I get a different error in a different class. If nothing better pops up, I'll give you credit

Comment: Okay, I think I got it this time. 
Context context = com.Juggle2.Menu.this.getContext();
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, StartGame.class));